# Possible reputation bug from bounty award

Tags: bug, reputation, bounty

I was awarded a 100 point bounty for [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37624). The user who offered/awarded the bounty got [100 reputation points deducted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa?tab=reputation). While the answer has a `+100` indicator next to it, I received 200 points added to [my reputation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1442/fred?tab=reputation) for the bounty (`+200 - Bounty` is indicated in my reputation history).

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but in the [answer revisions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/37624/revisions) you can see that `Bounty Ended with 100 reputation awarded` is listed twice (and `Notice removed Reward existing answer` is also doubled in the [question revisions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/37621/revisions)).

Is this a bug? If so, is it localized to Mi Yodeya, or is it network wide?

Comment: Shhhh! Just don't complain. `:-)`

Comment: Math here doesn't add up http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1442/fred?tab=bounties&sort=earned

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326911